# How to display list columns in Tab in the Ribbon? SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, development

I have a list called `empribbon` and I have created a custom ribbon `Tab` or `Group` and I have named it `General Info` as shown in the image:

[image: My default view for Edit tab]

In my custom tab I have also created a button; as shown in the following image

[image: My default view for General info tab]

Now what I want is: In the `EDIT` tab only the field `Title` must be shown there just like I did it in my photo

[image: How I want EDIT tab to be]

and in the `General Info` tab only those fields `Name` `Age` `Adress` and `Phone No` must be shown there just like I did it in my photo

[image: How I want General Info tab to be]

My code I used to create my General Info tab:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
   <CustomAction
     Id="CustomRibbonTab"
     Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
     RegistrationId="0x0100FF9897B958E2C74FB67BEFF08AFA1786"
     RegistrationType="ContentType">
     <CommandUIExtension>
       <CommandUIDefinitions>
         <CommandUIDefinition
           Location="Ribbon.Tabs._children">
           <Tab
             Id="Ribbon.CustomTab"
             Title="General Info"
             Description="general info"
             Sequence="501">
             <Scaling
               Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.Scaling">
               <MaxSize
                 Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.MaxSize"
                 GroupId="Ribbon.CustomTab.CustomGroup"
                 Size="OneLargeTwoMedium"/>
               <Scale
                 Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.Scaling.CustomTabScaling"
                 GroupId="Ribbon.CustomTab.CustomGroup"
                 Size="OneLargeTwoMedium" />
             </Scaling>
             <Groups Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.Groups">
               <Group
                 Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.CustomGroup"
                 Description="Custom Group!"
                 Title="Custom Group"
                 Sequence="52"
                 Template="Ribbon.Templates.CustomTemplate">
                 <Controls Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.CustomGroup.Controls">
                   <Button
                     Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.CustomGroup.CustomButton"
                     Command="CustomTab.CustomButtonCommand"
                     Sequence="15"
                     Description=""
                     LabelText="Custom Button"
                     Image32by32="/_layouts/images/PPEOPLE.GIF"
                     TemplateAlias="cust1"/>

                 </Controls>
               </Group>
             </Groups>
           </Tab>          
         </CommandUIDefinition>
         <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">
           <GroupTemplate Id="Ribbon.Templates.CustomTemplate">
             <Layout
               Title="OneLargeTwoMedium"
               LayoutTitle="OneLargeTwoMedium">
               <Section Alignment="Top" Type="OneRow">
                 <Row>
                   <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="cust1" />
                 </Row>
               </Section>
             </Layout>
           </GroupTemplate>
         </CommandUIDefinition>
       </CommandUIDefinitions>
       <CommandUIHandlers>
         <CommandUIHandler
           Command="CustomTab.CustomButtonCommand"
            CommandAction="javascript:alert('Hello, world!');" />
       </CommandUIHandlers>
     </CommandUIExtension>
   </CustomAction>
 </Elements>
```

How Can I do this?

Please Help me!

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution: create your own form in sharepoint designer and set `<tr>` with "Title" field visible, other `<tr>` with fields names (Name,Age,etc) set to `display:none;`. Then write function for your button which will toggle fields (for example, name it function 'toggleFields()') and set it to `CommandAction`. When you click this button fields will show/hide.

Function example:

```
function toggleFields(){
    $("[name^='SPBookmark_']").closest("tr").toggle()
}
```

Where `$("[name^='SPBookmark_']")` is selector for `<a></a>` which contains field name. Adapt it for your purposes and improve it how you want.